# P: Como puedo superponer elementos en un card? Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, web

Hola comunidad tengo un problema a a la hora de desarrollar un card, quiero poner botones y textos encima la imagen y no me esta funcionando, ahí dejo el código y imagen. Cuando le aplico un margin al botón me lo aplica al card completo, y yo lo que quiero es posicionar el botón por encima de la imagen. MUCHAS GRACIAS

```
  <div class="card-columns">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
           <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top text-center img-fluid" src="img/img1.jpg" alt="">
           </div><!--card-->
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJKFb.png

Answer (score 1):

En la documentacion de bootstrap te explica como puedes lograr lo que necesecitas

```
<div class="card bg-dark text-white">
  <img class="card-img" src="..." alt="Card image">
  <div class="card-img-overlay">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    <p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

fuente: [Bootstrap Overlays](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#image-overlays)